Can I overwrite a live vb.net code file behind an open aspx page without losing viewstate?
I don't think this is a problem, but just want to check with my peers for good measure.  If I overwrite the vb.net code file behind a live aspx web page/form that users have open, will ViewState or session vars be effected when they postback? For example...
In my dev environment, I navigated to the original form (from a referring page) and entered some information.  Saved it and kept the form open.  Uploaded the revised vb.net code behind.  Saved the form again, which is followed by an immediate refresh/update of the form data from the database on postback.  Navigated back to the referring page, which was stored in a ViewState var in the form I edited.  Saw that everything depending on ViewState was intact as hoped, and session vars were intact as expected.  Is this as safe as I think it is?  Thanks!
